# CDI instantiate and inject parent-child type beans is either ambigious or child types is not found

Tags: java, cdi

I have an interface like:

```java
public interface DateTimeService {
    ZonedDateTime now();

    void fixTo(ZonedDateTime date);

    void forget();
}
```

and I have two implementations of it. One for production where `fixTo` and `forget` throws exceptions and one for testing where we control time. Then I have a CDI config that depending on a flag instantiate the right type.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class Configuration {
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public DateTimeService dateTimeService(Configuration config) {
        if (config.isFakeDateTimeServiceEnabled()) {
            return new FakeDateTimeService();
        } else {
            return new DefaultDateTimeService();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I wanted to remove `fixTo` and `forget` from `DateTimeService` as they are only there so we can control time in tests. I made a new interface like:

```java
public interface FakeDateTimeService extends DateTimeService {
    // fixto and forget is moved from DateTimeService to here
}
```

I have a few injection points. Some is in production code, some is in test code. In production code I would like to only be able to access `DateTimeSerice`, in test code I want be able to get a handle on the extended service.

In prod code:

```java
    @Inject
    private DateTimeService dateTimeService;
```

In test code:

```java
    @Inject
    private FakeDateTimeService dateTimeService;
```

If I leave the config unchanged, then the test code will never find my extended service (as CDI seems to ignore the run-time type of the instance produced by the producer method).

If I update the config to instantiate both (in this case I can even inject the genuine service into the fake one), then production cannot wire together as fake also implements the `DateTimeService` interface and it causes ambiguity. At this point I could probably just use a qualifier, but I neither want to change my production code because of this nor have to have a fake date time service exist in production context.

I tried to veto bean creation but I failed to do so.

What I thought would/should work is instantiate the right type and programmatically add it to the bean context but examples I found was for CDI 2.0 while for now, relevant part of my code is stuck on CDI 1.2.

Probably at this point you can tell, that I'm not a CDI expert. So I'm opened for suggestion on good CDI read materials as well as concrete suggestions on this problem.

Otherwise, I'm about to give up and just live with a `DateTimeService` that have `fixTo` and `forget` methods.

Comment: CDI uses typesafe resolution and the important bit here are bean types - your `FakeDateTimeService` as a bean actually has types `{FakeDateTimeService, DateTimeService, Object}` (and any other extended class or implemented interface). As such it is eligible for injection into any injection point of those types hence the ambiguous resolution exception. If I get your intent correctly, then you might want to read up on CDI Alternatives and have `FakeDateTimeService` as an enabled alternative for tests hence replacing the `DateTimeService` in all its injection points in tests.

Comment: Other approach might be to have a CDI extension and veto the original type and register a new bean. With CDI 1.2 this would be somewhat more complex and still, the extension would need to be in place only for tests. I would rather look for a way to make this work with alternatives.

Comment: Absolutely go for alternatives (or maybe a specializer) that is only visible in the test classpath. Having switches that activate a dummy component in production frighten me, because a mistake might leave the production unstable or compromised. If the test code you are referring is only unit tests, you may even just mock the `DateTimeService`.

Comment: thank you guys. I understood the why the ambiguity, I just didn't know where to go next. I'll look both proposed solutions. Have a great day!

Comment: You might like to take a look at [ioc-unit](https://github.com/1and1/ioc-unit). By defining separate Testcode and productive (sut) code it is very easy to implicitly define the priority of of the FakeDateTimeService without Alternatives

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are doing it, you could use the following approaches, whereby some of them have already be mentioned in the comments.

### With alternatives

For testing you provide an own beans.xml, which defines the alternative for testing, which replaces the production one. You will have to keep them in sync, whereby the test beans.xml contains changes necessary for testing. Depending on the CDI implementation the beans.xml can be left out and @Alternative will be enough.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjsdf.html

```
interface DateTimeService  { ... }

// Active during production, beans.xml does not define alternative
class DefaultDateTimeService implements DateTimeService  { ... }

// Active during test, beans.xml defines alternative
@Alternative
class FakeDateTimeService implements DateTimeService { ... }

// Injection point stays the same.
@Inject
DateTimeService dateTimeService;

// Used in test environment
<beans ... >
    <alternatives>
        <class>FakeDateTimeService</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

### With Arquillian

With Aarquillian you can assemble the deployment yourself and exclude the DefaultDateTimeService implementation and replace it with the FakeDateTimeService implementation. With this approach you don't need to hack anything because during test, only FakeDateTimeService implementation will be visible to the CDI container.

http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/

### With CDI Extension

For testing you could provide an CDI extension and the FakeDateTimeService implementation in the test code, whereby the CDI Extension does veto the DefaultDateTimeService implementation.

```
package test.extension

public class VetoExtension implements Extension {

    public <T> void disableBeans(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T> pat) {
        // type matching
        if (DefaultDateTimeService.class.isAssignableFrom(pat.getAnnotatedType().getJavaClass())) {
            pat.veto();
        }
    }
}

// Define SPI provider file, assuming test/resources is on CDI classpath
src/test/resources/META-INF/services/javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension
// Single line you put in there
test.extension.VetoExtension
```

### Deltaspike @Exclude

Deltaspike is a CDI extension library which provides some useful utilities for CDI development and testing, also a CDITestRunner is provided. The @Exclude annotation is used by an extension which does the same as the example above but already implemented for you.

https://deltaspike.apache.org/

https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/test-control.html

https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/projectstage.html

You should choose an approach which doesn't pollute your source code and forces you to hack to much to get it running for testing.

I would prefer Arquillian because here you have full control about what is in the deployment and nothing in your production code has to change or be specially implemented so its testable.

With Deltaspike you can exclude production code for testing and replace them with test implementations.

If no additional library or framework can be used I would prefer the alternative approach, because its the least complicated one to use.